# What is the dimension of the set of all polynomials of degree ≤3 having a zero constant term?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm looking in my linear algebra book and the definition just says that dimension  of the number of elements in the linear space... so how many elements are in this linear space?

Comment: How can you say about the family $\left(X,X^{2},X^{3}\right)$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watch out! The dimension is the number of elements in a basis for your vector space. What is a basis for the vector space of all polynomials of degree $\leq 3$ having a zero constant term? Try $\{x, x^2, x^3\}$.

Answer (score 1):

### Hint:

representing a polynomial $ax^3 + bx^2 + cx$ by a vector $\left[\begin{smallmatrix} a \\ b \\ c\end{smallmatrix}\right]$. How much linear independent vectors (e.g. unit vectors) do you need to represent all possible vectors of this form?

Comment: 3? is that the right answer?

Comment: it is the right answer and I hope you see the unit vectors represent exactly $x$, $x^2$ and $x^3$ as the answer of [equin](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/214532/equin) states.